# Security Risks of Internet exposed Virtual Machine running on NAS

Tags: security, virtual-machines

I have a small business network that is currently locked down behind a security gateway.  However I'd like to expose a website.  The web server would be running on a virtual machine running on a NAS.

Assuming:
  - the exposed VM is on it's own network
  - only port 80 and port 443 are opened on this network

Is there any real risk that the Virtual Machine can be compromised in a way that would allow access to the underlying NAS, or other VM's running on it?

Comment: Pay for third party website hosting, it's cheap and will reduce your risk. If you must do this then create a DMZ on your network for your web server - ie a firewall between the internet and the web server, then another firewall between the web server and the internal network. If it's a simple website that doesn't need to contact the internal network just create a completely separate subnet for it. I wouldn't expose your whole network to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the risk is significant, and given the low cost of managed hosting, and the complications of running your own website, it doesn't make a lot of financial sense to operate it yourself. Once it becomes financially viable to support at least 2 fulltime, dedicated staff, then maybe think about bringing it back in-house but on dedicated hardware seperate from your back-office systems.

Comment: Seriously this. $5US/month for a VPS or less than that for a shared webhost account.

Comment: Yes, but then you have to add at least 3 hours per month on maintenance and patching - the reason its so so cheap for a VPS is because you do the the hard work yourself.

Comment: Well, shared hosting then.